# How to replace string in "select" statement

Tags: database, db2, db2-400

I need to add comma after every six digits ,but I don't know its length and I can't use loops. 
Thanks in advance.

I've tried REGEXP_REPLACE DB2 function, but it doesn't recognize my column as string.

For example , I need to replace "123456123456" with "123456, 123456".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide us with some code to look into. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please give us the table schema as well as the SQL where you used REGEXP_REPLACE.  It's possible you just need to `CAST` to a string but without this info, its hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select rtrim(xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:replace($s, "([0-9]{6})", "$1, ")' passing str as "s") as varchar(4000)), ', ')
from table(values ('123456123456')) t(str);
```

Comment: Works on my 10.5 as is. What's your db2 platform and version?

Comment: I don't know exact version, but it is lower than 10(maybe 9.7).

Comment: Do you know another  variant or why REGEXP_REPLACE doesn't work?

Comment: [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061496.html) was introduced in 11.1 only. BTW, I checked my example on 9.7 and 10.1. This works on 10.1 as is. There is no 2-nd parameter in the `rtrim` function (which removes trailing ', ' in our case) in 9.7, but `fn:replace` works there. So, it's very strange, that this example doesn't work for your db2. Check the exact db2 platform and version you use.

Comment: I've tried it on 4 systems( with  V7R1,   V7R2,  V7R3, V7R4 versions), but it works nowhere.

Comment: You should tag your questions with the [db2-400] tag. [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscaregexp_replace.htm) function for DB2 for IBM i. What's your exact statement using this function, and what's the exact error and message text you get?